# What is the best way to design a form for an associative (table) entity?

Tags: forms, database-design

I was wondering if I can get feedback about whether this is best way to design a form for an associative entity.

So I have a users and events table with attendees as the associative (table) entity. The attendee table has...

- its own id (PK)
- a user id (FK)
- an event id (FK)
- a date.

My current form handles options to mark attendance to a number of events, and the ability to remove (update) their attendance.
This is done through checkboxes. If the checkbox is checked, you are attending, if not checked, you are not attending.
My form then handles the scenario like this...

```
<!-- 
  An array of hidden attendee table ids (in this case the database 
  has found the user previously marked attendance for 3 events):
-->
<input type="hidden" name="attendee_id[]" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="attendee_id[]" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="attendee_id[]" value="3">

<!-- A number of event ids for a specific date: -->
<input type="checkbox" name="attendee_checkbox[]" value="15">Event One
<input type="checkbox" name="attendee_checkbox[]" value="16">Event Two
<input type="checkbox" name="attendee_checkbox[]" value="17">Event Three
<input type="checkbox" name="attendee_checkbox[]" value="18">Event Four
```

When the form is submitted...

First, I have the database delete all the rows in the attendee table by id (attendee_id[]).
I then have the database insert new rows where attendee_checkbox[] post variables have returned.
So for example, the user unchecks two events, and now "Event three" value: 17 is submitted as the only event id in the attendee table.

So would you say this is an acceptable way to handle this scenario, or would you handle it differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really about database design. Anyhow...

The approach you describe works, but it doesn't appear very elegant. When the user just checks or unchecks a box, you'll delete all those records and build them anew. But there is no compelling reason against this.

Still, depending on the capabilities of both your data access layer and/or GUI layer, there might be better solutions.

If you use an ORM framework like Hibernate or JPA, you might read the user with all her attendance records. You will probably have done this already to display the attendances, so it won't even mean additional effort. Now you can iterate over the collection of user.attendances programmatically, delete and insert according to the current checkbox values, and then persist the user, cascading down to the attendance.

Modern GUI frameworks like AngularJS allow to react on a single user input. In this case, you would have the framework listen to each check/uncheck event and issue a REST call to the server for exactly one addition or removal. Or, if you don't want such a call for each single change event, you might collect the issued changes (like "insert abc", "delete def"...) on the client and submit the whole bunch of them to the server, which will then exactly know what to insert and delete.